# running a program in a subdirectory

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

Say my current working directory is `C:\Users\neubert\Documents\` or something. Let's also say that I have a subdirectory in that directory - `subdir` - and a file in that subdirectory - `filename.exe`.

When I'm in `C:\Users\neubert\Documents\` with `cmd` and then do `subdir\filename` I get a `The system cannot find the path specified.` error.

So is it not possible to run programs inside subdirectories with `cmd`?

Comment: I just attempted what you described, I had no problem, can you provide the console output as text or a screenshot? **I suspect I know what is going on but I won't post an answer until I know precisely what is going on which the output will allow me to do.**  If couldn't run executable from a subdirectory, you couldn't type "calc" in a command prompt, and have it start the default calculator program.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a program with `cmd`, it's current directory is set to the path you see at the command prompt. I'm almost certain that the program in question has some dependency on another file in its residing directory, which in this case is **not** its current directory, so it can't find the file. If the program didn't exist, you would see something like this:

```
'sub\blargh.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

You can prove that the current directory is different by creating a batch file named `loc.bat` in a folder called `test`, containing `echo %CD%`. When you run it with `test\loc` from the parent directory, you'll see the command prompt's directory, not the one that contains the script.

It's certainly possible to launch programs in other folders, but you need to be careful about their current directory. To start a program in a certain directory, you can use `start /b /wait /d folder program`. If I found myself needing to do that often, I might make a batch file containing `start /b /wait /d %1 %2` and put it on my `PATH`.